# How can I handle ProgressDialog on orientation change?

Tags: android, exception, progressdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with orientation change with a ProgressDialog showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695484/how-to-deal-with-orientation-change-with-a-progressdialog-showing)

```
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:378)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:223)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
08-14 17:23:31.078: E/AndroidRuntime(25099):    at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:951)
```

Above is what I am getting when I rotate my screen while my progress dialog is being shown. 
How can I handle this problem...

Comment: Have you tried this `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity?

Comment: I tried.. It worked.. but my activity layout is different in landscape and portrait. when I start with portrait.. the landscape's original layout is replaced with potrait's layout. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one

 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:name=".your.package">
```

Comment: I tried.. It worked.. but my activity layout is different in landscape and portrait. when I start with portrait.. the landscape's original layout is replaced with potrait's layout. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

please insert this line to your activity  in **menifest**

```
 <activity
            android:name="your activity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
          />
```

Comment: I tried.. It worked.. but my activity layout is different in landscape and portrait. when I start with portrait.. the landscape's original layout is replaced with potrait's layout. Can you help me out?

Comment: Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)